# A 'RenderBadPicture' Xerror rarely occurs from xrender extension

Tags: c, x11, motif

Recently, I tried to upgrade the Motif library (libXm.so) to a newer version (2.3.3) with XFT support for rendering mutli-language characters.

I ran the application and an very annoying X error occurs sometimes (many hours) randomly:

> RenderBadPicture (invalid Picture parameter) in RenderChangePicture,
>   RenderCompositeGlyphs8 or RenderSetPictureClipRectangles in extension
>   RENDER.

Error is produced asynchronously first by X11 low-level libraries. This is a summary of the back trace.

_XError
_XReply
XQueryColor
_XmXftDrawString
_XmStringDrawSegment
XmStringDraw
XtDispatchEventToWidget
XtDispatchEvent
XtAppProcessEvent
main

Back trace could change a little from a crash to an other.

Please see an example in my code to draw a string in a drawable:

```
XftDraw xftDraw = XftDrawCreate(dpy, drawable, DefaultVisual(dpy, screenNum), colormap);
XftDrawStringUtf8(xftDraw, xftcolor, xftFont, x, y, (const FcChar8*)line, strlen(line));
XftDrawDestroy(xftDraw);
```

Running on:
 - CentOS 6.5.
 - X version 11 Revision 6 (Xft 2.3.1)
 - single thread

Question:
Crash is unreproductible, have you some idea about a possible origin of this error ?